# PHPMailer attachment: mail client doesn't decode

Tags: php, phpmailer

using PHPMailer's AddAttachment method on PHP 5, it seems I can't get any mail client to decode base64 section.

Practically, receiving the e-mail message with Thunderbird, instead of my attached file "asyF074.tmp", I find attached a "Part1.2" file, which contains section headers (

```
name="asyF074.tmp"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="asyF074.tmp"
```

) followed by base64 representation of file contents.

I can't figure out what is going wrong with the attachment:

```
    $filename = tempnam ( "" , "asy" );

$f = fopen($filename, "wb");
fwrite($f, $tbl, strlen($tbl));
fclose($f);

/*
 * Send mail...
 */
$mail = new phpmailer();
$mail->IsSMTP(); 
$mail->From = "andrew@" . $domain;
$mail->FromName = "Andrew";
$mail->Host = $mail_host;  
$mail->Port = $mail_port;
$mail->AddAddress($mail_destination);
$mail->IsHTML(true);    
$mail->Subject = "2011 Polls";
$mail->Body = $msg;
$mail->AddAttachment($filename, "2011-Polls.xls", "quoted-printable", "application/vnd.ms-excel");
$mail->Send(); // send message

unlink($filename);
```

Also, even if I explicitly set encoding to "quoted-printable", the attachment always comes encoded in base64.

Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

... found! I don't know why, but it was due to the PHPMailer version I was using (I know what you're thinking: "This guy blew the former download", but I can assure you that I downloaded the proper lib).

I re-downloaded (2 days later) the [*same* library](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpmailer/files/phpmailer%20for%20php5_6/PHPMailer%20v5.1/) for PHP 5 and now it's working.

Didn't have the time to check, but there was something wrong into the library code.

Comment: this is really not a helpful self-answer

Answer (score 0):

It may not be an answer to your problem but I suggest you try Zend_Mail from the Zend_Framework I've never say problems like these using it.